# finding eigenvalues of a very huge matrix

Tags: python, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalue

I am trying to implement spectral clustering algorithm for a community detection in graph problem.

I have very huge matrix to calculates its Eigenvectors, matrix of > 1Mx1M.

Numpy and Scipy needs the matrix to be on memory to calculate it, which is impossible in my case.

Is there any other lib or package that calculates Eigenvectors and values on disk instead of memory (just like [HDF5](http://www.h5py.org/) allows us to store and manipulate data on disk)?

Or is there any solution you can suggest?

Comment: Is your matrix sparse (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)?  I hope so!

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html

Comment: no it's not sparse :( that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you @brainjam but this uses RAM too, and my problem is with memory usage, such a matrix can't be loaded on RAM (in my knowledge)

Comment: Doesn't your OS have swap space? Have you tried it? If so then what is the error?

Comment: @GuyCoder yes it has (8Gb), but how can i explicitly use it? there is no specific error but it's consuming a lot of Memory till the OS freezes. (I'm using Linux)

Comment: Linux is not my primary OS, but the concept should be same. It is there by default and automatically used. However in rare cases you need to increase the size of the reserved disk space if you run out; that is OS specific. Start with [Using a swap space](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/using-swap.html).  I do know that on Linux you can also use the resource monitor and on my Ubuntu it does show how much RAM and how much swap space are being used in real time. At this point I can not give more details because it would be guessing and not from actual usage.

Comment: I just calculated 1M x 1M and realized you will need 1T to hold that. I have never seen a swap space that large, but it should work in theory.

Comment: I am getting MemoryError,

`>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100000,100000))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 953, in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:10897)
MemoryError
`

although the swap is free (90%).

Comment: oups! yeah that was a bad exemple to test on cauz it needed more than RAM+SWAP that i have, so yes @GuyCoder i think I should increase the SWAP size then try again. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the size of your swap file.

See: 
[What is virtual memory?](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/vm-intro.html)
[Creating a swap space](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/swap-space.html)
[Using a swap space](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/using-swap.html)

Also systems typically report on in real time in the resource monitor.

For Ubuntu

[[image: Example of resource monitor showing swap space usage]]